# How to loop through Membership List?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have a list of all memberships:

```
Dim allUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast(Of MembershipUser).ToList
```

Despite my searches, I have been unable to figure out how to loop through this to do something like the following.  I want to loop through and retrieve a record, if the record contains a certain value, add the user to a new collection.

```
for each allusers as user

  ' get user profile
  ' if user profile has a certain value, add it to another collection

end for each
```

Then, once the new collection is full, output that collection to my view.

Does that make sense?  How can I do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function GetUsers() As IEnumerable(Of MembershipUser)

    Dim newListOfUsers = New List(Of MembershipUser)()
    Dim users As MembershipUserCollection = Membership.GetAllUsers()
    For Each user As MembershipUser In users
        If user.Comment = "A Leather Glove" Then
            newListOfUsers.Add(user)
        End If
    Next

    Return newListOfUsers
End Function
```

Comment: That should work, though I haven't tried it yet.  P.S. I love that SNL skit (pre-edit by Mystere Man)!

Answer (score 4):

Added C# version:

```
    var newListOfUsers = new List<MembershipUser>();
    Membership.GetAllUsers().OfType<MembershipUser>().ToList().ForEach( user =>
                                                                                {
                                                                                    if(user.Comment.Equals("A Leather Glove")) newListOfUsers.Add(user);
                                                                                });
```